# i am having trouble in updating my chaincode of fabcar

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

How can I write my own chaincode and run it on fabcar sample.
As I know that chaincode is run under the docker container now what is the procedure to change the existing chaincode that is running on fabric network and deploy my own chaincode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install and instantiate another chaincode.

For example, supposing you have your file .go with the new chaincode, called "chaincode2.go", the procedure is:

```
peer chaincode install -n chaincode2 -v 1.0 -p github.com/chaincode/chaincode_example02/go/
```

Next, instantiate:

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto/ordererOrganizations/example.com/orderers/orderer.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/tlsca.example.com-cert.pem -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n chaincode2 -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":["init","a", "100", "b","200"]}' -P "AND ('Org1MSP.peer','Org2MSP.peer')"
```

After installing and instantiating, you can query, invoke and much more.
This was just an example, hope it helps.